# Why do some apt installation commands require confirmation?

Tags: apt

Some `apt` installation commands, like `apt-get install kate`, prompt for confirmation, whilst others do not.

Is there some reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get` asks for confirmation in essentially two circumstances.

1. when it needs to do more than it has been directly requested to do,
   to satisfy the request made. E.g. if you asked for a package to be
   installed or deleted, if it needs to perform actions involving other
   packages not explicitly mentioned, whether the action is
   installation or deletion, it quite properly asks for confirmation
   first.
2. when it is asked to perform an action that may be harmful to the
   system. Attempting to remove an essential package, for example, will
   trigger this warning.

   ```
   # apt-get remove apt
   [...]
   WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
   This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
     apt
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 27 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
   After this operation, 12.5 MB disk space will be freed.
   You are about to do something potentially harmful.
   To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
    ?]
   ```